# How to return to a nested route when switching between tabs with ShellRoute and GoRouter 5.0?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I’m trying to get nested navigation to work with `ShellRoute` in go_router 5.0.

As the example below shows, I can correctly navigate to the (nested) product page when clicking on a product.

But if I switch to the cart tab and back to products, I'm taken back to the (root) products page rather than the (nested) product page:

[image: ShellRoute example with GoRouter 5.0]

This is how I've setup my router:

```dart
enum AppRoute {
  products,
  product,
  cart,
  account,
}

final goRouter = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/products',
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: [
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
        builder: (context, state, child) {
          return ScaffoldWithBottomNavBar(child: child);
        },
        routes: [
          // Products
          GoRoute(
            path: '/products',
            name: AppRoute.products.name,
            redirect: (context, state) {
              print(state.toString());
              return null;
            },
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              restorationId: state.pageKey.value,
              child: const ProductsListScreen(),
            ),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: ':id',
                name: AppRoute.product.name,
                pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                  final productId = state.params['id']!;
                  // TODO: Cupertino slide transition
                  return MaterialPage(
                    key: state.pageKey,
                    restorationId: state.pageKey.value,
                    child: ProductScreen(productId: productId),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // Shopping Cart
          GoRoute(
            path: '/cart',
            name: AppRoute.cart.name,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: const ShoppingCartScreen(),
            ),
          ),
          // Account page
          GoRoute(
            path: '/account',
            name: AppRoute.account.name,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: const AccountScreen(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```

This is the `build` method of the `ScaffoldWithBottomNavBar` widget:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: widget.child,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black87,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.list,
            ),
            label: 'Products'.hardcoded,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: const ShoppingCartIcon(),
            label: 'Cart'.hardcoded,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
            ),
            label: 'Account'.hardcoded,
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index) => _tap(context, index),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the tab button callback, I do this:

```dart
  void _tap(BuildContext context, int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedIndex = index); // used for the highlighted state
    // navigate to the target route based on the tab index
    if (index == 0) {
      context.goNamed(AppRoute.products.name);
    } else if (index == 1) {
      context.goNamed(AppRoute.cart.name);
    } else if (index == 2) {
      context.goNamed(AppRoute.account.name);
    }
  }
```

I understand why this does **not** work since I’m telling GoRouter to **go** to each of the (root) routes inside the `ShellRoute`.

Ideally, I'd want a way to switch to a specific tab by index, and have GoRouter "remember" if it was on a nested or top-level route.

*Note that unlike `TabBar`, `BottomNavigationBar` does **not** have a controller I can use to switch the index.*

GoRouter 5.0 is new and there isn't much documentation or examples showing these kind of common use cases.

Anyone knows how to approach this?

*Note: one of my ideas was to store the selected product ID as application state somewhere, and use it inside a `redirect` function inside the `/products` route, but then it becomes complex to know where I should reset that state to `null`, and my experiments with `NavigationObserver` did not yield the desired result.*

**Update 28th Jun 2023**

GoRouter [7.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/changelog#710) added a new `StatefulShellRoute` class to support this.

I've written a full tutorial explaining how to use it:

- [Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar with Stateful Nested Routes using GoRouter](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-bottom-navigation-bar-nested-routes-gorouter/)

Comment: hello, how are you able to pass the data from your ProductsListScreen to the ProductScreen route without any loading ?

Answer (score 6):

Sadly this is the missing piece to make it the perfect router.
As you noticed this is the issue to track and the team is already on it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99124.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **StatefulSheelRoute** instead of **ShellRoute**